# How can I get my ClassLoader resource to use my maven properties?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, environment-variables, maven-3

I have a `BaseTask` in Java EE that provides a URL to other classes.  This URL changes depending on if we are building for `dev`, `test` or `prod`.

In my `src/main/resources` I have a file called `server.properties`.  This file has one entry like:

```
urls.main=${urls.main}
```

Next, we have three files named `dev.properties`, `test.properties` and `prod.properties` located in `src/main/filters`.

Each of those files have one entry but as an example, `dev.properties` contains an entry like:

```
urls.main=http://localhost/somepath
```

Now, I have the following setup in my pom:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <build>
            <filters>
                <filter>src/main/filters/dev.properties</filter>
            </filters>

            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
    ... repeat for "test.properties" and "prod.properties"...
</profiles>
```

OK, so now I can perform the following:

```
mvn -Pdev package
```

and the `EAR` file is built along with a `server.properties` file with an entry in it like:

```
urls.main=http://localhost/somepath
```

So the actual file renders correctly inside the EAR file.  But, when I try to load the property from Java, it uses `${urls.main}` instead.

The code I'm using in Java to load the property is:

```
private static final String getURL() {

    String url = "";
    try {
        url = getProperty("urls.main");     // returns "${urls.main}" instead of http://localhost/somepath
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return url;
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something stupid but what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

BTW, This isn't all of the code, I do close out streams, etc.  I just didn't post everything so that I can keep the post easier to read.  :-)

Comment: I usually make this part of the server configuration. You can add URLs to JNDI in the server and then inject them with @Resource or access via the JNDI apis. I dislike having environment dependent deployable units. They tend to multiply as you gain environments.

Comment: Normally, I would agree.  And I've explored this option.  One issue I had with it was getting this to work with OpenEJB that runs an embedded Jetty server.  Which I guess could be a different question.  I might re-examine that too.  But I'd still like to know how to fix this.  Thanks.

Comment: I would be looking for other copies of this property, perhaps directly in the server class path or elsewhere